# Recursively update nested object values for specific keys based on another object

Tags: javascript, oop, recursion

*** UPDATED object structure ***

I'd like to update recursively the property values of mainObject from the properties that exist in updatingObject.

```
let mainObject = {
  age: 24,
  isMarried: false,
  pets: {
    dog: {
      name: "Juniper",
      age: 3
    },
    cat: {
      name: "Spasia",
      age: 7
    }
 },
 hobbies: {
    mountainRelated: ["hiking", "snowboarding"]
 }
}

let updatingObject = {
   pets: {
      cat: {
         age: 8
      }
   }
}
```

I've added a Codepen link to the problem below: what I still have to do is to find the correct properties to be updated (for example the "age" property is common for more objects).

TL;DR: cat age should be 8 in the mainObject

https://codepen.io/Dragosb/pen/bGwypKz?editors=0012

Comment: Is the value to update always a primitive value? Also what should happen if the update object contains a non-existing value in the mainObject? For example, `{ cat: { breed: 'breed' } }`

Comment: It containes both primitive and structural data types. If there is a new property that isn't reflected in the mainObject, it will be ignored.

Comment: So if the `updateObject` is `{ pets: { cat: { age: { year: 8 } } } }`, then the `cat` portion within `mainOjbect` should becomes `{ cat: { name: 'Spasia', age: { year: 8 } } }`, am I correct?

Comment: No, if this is the case, mainObject should not update. The mainObject's structure does not change; if you provide a corresponding property inside the updatingObject with a new value, it will update the mainObject (only for those where the same structure is identified), and ignore other structures or properties which cannot be found in the mainObject.

Comment: so you update only existing `strings` and `numbers`. How about arrays ? can you update nth element of array ? and if so how would the update object be ?

Comment: I would act as follows: first I would exclude the array case, because it complicates things, and thus we would work only with object structures and primitive values.

For a more complete solution, I would be satisfied by including arrays, as long as they only contain primitive values (strings, numbers etc - but no objects or other arrays)

Answer (score 7):

You can traverse in sync

```js
let mainObject = {
  age: 24,
  isMarried: false,
  pets: {
    dog: { name: "Juniper", age: 3 },
    cat: { name: "Spasia", age: 7 }
 },
 hobbies: {
    mountainRelated: ["hiking", "snowboarding"]
 }
}

let updatingObject = {
   pets: {
      cat: {
         age: 8,
name:'gabriele'
      }
   }
}


function updateObject(target, update){
   // for each key/value pair in update object
   for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(update)){
      // if target has the relevant key and
      // the type in target and update is the same
      if (target.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof(value) === typeof(target[key])){
        // update value if string,number or boolean
        if (['string','number','boolean'].includes(typeof value) || Array.isArray(value)){
          target[key] = value;
        } else {
          // if type is object then go one level deeper
          if (typeof value === 'object'){
             updateObject(target[key], value)
          }
        }
      }
   }
}

updateObject(mainObject,updatingObject)
console.log(mainObject);
```

Comment: Neat and clear answer! Give you an upvote

Comment: This is a very elegant answer, and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Again, thank you, it was very helpful and your contribution to the community is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

We can write a function that does this without mutating the original object, in a fairly simple manner.  This `merge` function breaks the original and update objects into key-value pairs, then keeps all those whose keys are only in one of them, and, for those in both, if both values are objects recursively calling `merge` on them, otherwise choosing the update value.  The resulting key-value pairs are then put back into an object.

Here is an implementation:

```js
const merge = (a, b) => Object .fromEntries ([
  ... Object .entries (a) .filter (([k]) => !(k in b)),
  ... Object .entries (b) .filter (([k]) => !(k in a)),
  ... Object. entries (b) .filter (([k]) => (k in a)) .map (([k, v]) => 
        [k, Object (v) === v && Object (a [k]) === a [k] ? merge (a [k], v) : v]
      ),
])


const mainObject = {age: 24, isMarried: false, pets: {dog: { name: "Juniper", age: 3 }, cat: { name: "Spasia", age: 7 }}, hobbies: {mountainRelated: ["hiking", "snowboarding"]}}
const updatingObject = {pets: {cat: {age: 8, name:'gabriele'}}}


console .log (merge (mainObject, updatingObject))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that while the resulting object is a new one, we use a form of structural sharing between this and the input objects.  For instance, if you push `'hangliding'` onto the array `hobbies.mountainRelated` in the resulting object, we will update `mainObject` values as well.  While we could change this behavior, it helps reduce memory consumption, so I wouldn't do so without good reason.

Note that this does not try to deal with more complicated scenarios, such as cyclic objects.  It also does not do anything to work with arrays.  Arrays add [numerous complexities](https://gist.github.com/CrossEye/ac9ae1cafad6e29963c90c748620d848), and if you need them, I would suggest looking at the equivalent functions in a library such as Ramda's [`mergeDeepRight`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeDeepRight) (disclaimer: I'm an author) or lodash's [`merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge), or dedicated tools like [`deepmerge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge).

Comment: Very interesting approach, and indeed, it is likely that I will work with more complex objects which will contain objects inside arrays and so on - I will look into tools such as those mentioned by yourself, but for now I find that Gabriele Petrioli's answer is a perfect fit and satisfies for now all the scenarios that I needed.

Comment: Very useful to me. it solves my level of complexity requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The below approach solves the problem by first constructing the access path to the property of an object, then access and modify the `mainObject` according to the access path constructed from the `updatingObject`.

```js
let mainObject = {
  age: 24,
  isMarried: false,
  pets: {
    dog: {
      name: 'Juniper',
      age: 3,
    },
    cat: {
      name: 'Spasia',
      age: 7,
    },
  },
  hobbies: {
    mountainRelated: ['hiking', 'snowboarding'],
  },
};

let updatingObject = {
  pets: {
    cat: {
      age: 8,
    },
  },
  hobbies: {
    mountainRelated: ['biking'],
    none: 'not updated',
  },
};

function updateGivenObject(mainObject, updatingObject) {
  const mainObjPaths = [];
  const updateObjPaths = [];

  buildPath(mainObject, mainObjPaths);
  buildPath(updatingObject, updateObjPaths);

  console.log('mainObjPaths:', mainObjPaths);
  console.log('updateObjPaths :', updateObjPaths );

  updateObjPaths.forEach(path => {
    const newValue = getPropByPath(updatingObject, path);

    setPropByPath(mainObject, path, newValue);
  });
}

function buildPath(obj, accumulatedPaths, currentPaths = []) {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
      accumulatedPaths.push([...currentPaths, key].join('.'));
    } else {
      buildPath(obj[key], accumulatedPaths, [...currentPaths, key]);
    }
  });
}

function getPropByPath(obj, path) {
  const pathArr = path.split('.');
  let value = obj;

  pathArr.forEach(key => {
    value = value[key];
  });

  return value;
}

function setPropByPath(obj, path, newValue) {
  const pathArr = path.split('.');
  let value = obj;

  pathArr.forEach((key, idx) => {
    if (value[key] === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    if (idx === pathArr.length - 1) {
      value[key] = newValue;
    } else {
      value = value[key];
    }
  });

  return value;
}

updateGivenObject(mainObject, updatingObject);
console.log(mainObject);

console.log(mainObject.pets.cat.age);
console.log(mainObject.hobbies.mountainRelated[0]);
console.log(mainObject.hobbies.none);
```

However, the above algorithm depends heavily on shared mutable state and should be careful about it.